# Working with Date functions mysql and adding day to date while keeping track

Tags: mysql, ddl, database-trigger

So I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `chittytransactions` (
  `ChittyTransactionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AuctionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ChittyAccNo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TransRefence` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Reference from actual Bank transaction',
  `TransStatus` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'If Transaction Pending or Cleared',
  `ClearanceDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `PaymentMethod` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0- Cash, 1- bank transfer, 2- personal credit etc'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Im creating a trigger that checks the `Date` and the `clearanceDate` to see if the `clearanceDate` is greater than the actual date then add a late fee. I have this so far:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS chitty_before_trig;

DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER chitty_before_trig BEFORE INSERT ON chittytransactions
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
  DECLARE `userId` INT(11);

  SELECT `UserId`
  INTO `userId`
  FROM chittyusers
  WHERE ChittyAccNo = NEW.ChittyAccNo;

    IF NEW.ClearanceDate <> NEW.`Date` THEN
            UPDATE `chittyusers` SET LatePaymentFee = 50 WHERE UserId = userId;
    END IF;
 END;;
 DELIMITER;
```

Using the date functions how can i check if a day has gone by etc and add a calculate late payment for each day?Please anything would be great Thank you.

Comment: You actually shouldn't need to store the late fee in the table unless you need to access it a lot, like, *really* a lot. Normally with a value that can always be *derived* from other values in the database (especially if they're in the same table) you would simply calculate them each time you need them. Views are often used for this purpose.

Comment: no late fee would depend on the date. like if another day goes by the late fee would change constantly. any idea how?

Comment: Tell me how the late fee is calculated.

Comment: so if the cleared date of late fee is greater than the actual date the payment was meant to be made then a late fee payment is added based on the day. maybe like +10 per each day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood the question, then something like

```
IF NEW.ClearanceDate > NEW.`Date` THEN
  UPDATE chittyusers
    SET LatePaymentFee = 10 * DATEDIFF(NEW.ClearanceDate, NEW.`Date`)
    WHERE UserId = userId;
END IF;
```

would work with your current schema. [`DATEDIFF(date1, date2)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) returns the number of days between `date1` and `date2` - the result is negative if `date1` is earlier than `date2`. Note I've changed the comparison operator from `<>` to `>` so the late fee is applied if `ClearanceDate` is after `Date`, but not if it's before.

I should point out that having a bare numeric constant like `10` in your code like that is considered very bad form. A slightly better way would be to declare a local variable named something like `baseLateFee`, set it to 10, and then use the variable in your calculation. A much better alternative, especially if there's any possibility that `baseLateFee` will ever change, would be to store it in a table somewhere so you can update it without having to find and change all the code that depends on it.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. yea i though about the option of having different table for late payment that changes